Properties of group action of normal subgroups
I'm currently reading Dixon's "Permutation groups". It states that when a group $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$ (let's denote this as $G\curvearrowright X$), the orbits of a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ must form a block system of $G\curvearrowright X$.
Initially, I thought that there was a one-to-one correspondence between block systems of $G$ and normal subgroups that fix each block setwise. If so, for each block system, there would be a corresponding unique normal subgroup.
However, I realized this isn't always the case. For example, consider the trivial block system of $S_n$. Both $S_n$ itself and $A_n$ are normal subgroups corresponding to this trivial block system. ($A_n$ is transitive, so its orbit would be the entire set.)
Therefore, the property that the orbits of a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ must form a block system of $G\curvearrowright X$ doesn't actually provide any hint about the normality of $N$ if $N$ is transitive.
So, apart from this property, what other unique characteristics do normal subgroups have when acting on a set? I'm looking forward to hearing from math experts on this.

crossposted : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4972518/properties-of-group-action-of-normal-subgroups
